# clarification on inequalities

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

I'm reading this [proof](http://www.noar.technion.ac.il/images/attachments/Scitech/Random-graphs-from-jeh-Feb-06-2010.pdf) (page 7), and get confused by the ending part , quoted here:

Take $c$ a constant less than $\sqrt{2}$. Then

> Since $var(x) \leq n^{3-2c^{2}}+n^{2-c^{2}}, E(x) \leq n^{2-c^{2}}$, and
> $E^{2}(x) \leq n^{4-2c^{2}}$, it follows that $var(x) \leq E^{2}(x)$.

What's the reason it follows that $var(x) \leq E^{2}(x)$? Is it because $E^{2}$ is on the order of 4 while $var(x)$ is on the order of 3?

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion cannot possibly be valid the way you have put it, because you have
$$Var(x)\le\hbox{something}\ ,\quad E^2(x)\le\hbox{something}\ ,$$
and you are asked to conclude
$$Var(x)\le E^2(x)\ .$$
This is in effect the same as asking "$a\le10$, $b\le20$, which is bigger, $a$ or $b$?"  There is no way to know.

I suggest you look carefully at earlier parts of the paper, perhaps there is more information which will help.

Comment: something i forgot to put in the question: we also know that $E(x^{2}) =E(x)$. Would this in anyway solve my confusion?

Comment: Can't see it.  Your conclusion will then be true iff $E(x)\le0$ or $E(x)\ge\frac12$.  Do you know if either of those is true?

Comment: nope nothing. i think i'm giving up. thanks anyway for helping i really appreciate it :)